# Why using “Reformat Code” functionality some methods are differently formatted?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, code-formatting

In PhpStorm 2021.1 working with Laravel 9 I periodically use “Reformat Code” functionality with all content of the file selected.

But some methods of this file looks differently formatted :

```php
    public function setBannerId(int $value): self
    {
        $this->bannerId = $value;

        return $this;
    }

...
    public
    function setDescriptionSize(
        int $value
    ): self {
        $this->descriptionSize = $value;

        return $this;
    }
```

I dislike a way the second method is formatted. I want all methods to be formatted as the first method?

**UPDATED :**
“Reformat Code” tab https://prnt.sc/cxkkYQdcRPjd printscreen

Can it be done?

Comment: Can't reproduce that on a default code style. Do you have anything changed in it? Does it happen with a "Default" code style template?

Comment: Where can I check code style template?

Comment: @duck_in_hat, I provided “Reformat Code” tab printscreen. Please check